# How to I make this PHP function more efficient?

Tags: php, html, echo, template-engine, performance

I want to find out a more efficient way of going about this function:

```
<?php
function zipError($title, $desc) {
    echo '<style type="text/css">';
    echo 'body { margin:0;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;background:#DDD;color:#1A1A1A; }';
    echo 'h1 { color:#FFF;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;text-align:center; }';
    echo 'h2 { color:#1C1C1C;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;padding-bottom:4px;border-bottom:1px solid #AAA; }';
    echo '#error#head { background:#1C1C1C;padding:10px;;border-bottom:5px solid #FFF; }';
    echo '#error#content { border:1px solid #AAA;background:#FFF;padding:20px;width:780px;margin:30px auto; }';
    echo 'p { text-align:center;padding:10px;color:#1A1A1A;font-family:verdana; }';
    echo '</style>';
    echo '<title>' . $title . '</title>';
    echo '<div id="error head"><h1>An error has occurred.</h1></div>';
    echo '<div id="error content"><h2>'.$title.'</h2><p>'.$desc.'</p></div>';
}
```

This code is used to throw an error. For example:

```
die(zipError('Session Not Found', 'Your session has not been found! Please re-login now!'));
```

Although this gets the job done, I'm trying to learn, so therefore I want to make this function more efficient, and not hard coded. Any ideas?

Comment: why are you not using a `css` file ?

Comment: I guess I could do that, but even if I do do that, then I would still hard-code HTML... I want a more efficient work-around this.

Comment: Why use a function that just handles output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's look like error template, I will do something like this:

create sparate error tamplate: e.g error.php:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <style>
      //style here...
     </style>
     <title><?= $title?></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       //and soon ...
   </body>
```

and a function:

```
public function zipError($title, $desc){
    include('error.php');
}
```

and usage:

```
 ... die(zipError('Session Not Found', 'Your session has not been found! Please re-login now!'));
```

Now, You can edit/change your error template easily as long as it keep echoing `$title` and `$desc` and any other parameter you want to.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is to drop out of PHP for all the HTML code and jump back in for the echoing of data. It just makes it a bit more readable from a maintenance point of view.

Next, use a separate CSS file so that it can be shared. It could be its own little file or incorporated into a larger one.

That's about it really. There isn't really a lot of php to optimize to be honest

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
echo "Output text/HTML using one statement
     instead of many, which can include\n
     line breaks and can span multiple lines";
```

OR

```
Only drop into PHP to output variables like <?=$var?> or <?php echo $var; ?>
```

Also, **die** and **exit** output the parameter passed - in this case the return value of **zipError()**. So either return the string from **zipError** rather than echoing it, or make things easier when calling the function and **exit** inside the function instead of wrapping the call with **die()**.